# Continuations in C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures, continuations

I have a question regarding continuations in C#. I have an example here from the book, *Real World Functional Programming* by Tomas Petricek and Jon Skeet.

```
void StringLengthCont(string s, Action<int> cont) {
   cont(s.Length); 
}

void AddLengthsCont() {
 StringLengthCont("One", x1 =>
    StringLengthCont("Two", x2 =>
        Console.WriteLine(x1 + x2)
   ))
}
```

Now this is very confusing for me. In this case, we have a method, `StringLengthCont` which expects a string, `s` and an `Action<int> cont` and it then invokes that `Action<int>` with the length of `s` as an argument.

So far I understand. But the inner lambda of the last call to `StringLengthCont` doesn't that have signature of `Action<int,int>` ? It seems to me it takes two integers, adds them together and returns a void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the inner lambda of the last call to StringLengthCont doesn't that
>   have signature of Action ?

No. What happens is the following:

You call `StringLengthCont` the first time, which takes an `Action<int>`. The actual action being passed (as a Lambda Expression) calls `StringLengthCont` again. The second time, it passes "Two" as the string parameter, and creates a parameter named `x2` which is being passed to `StringLengthCont` (the second) as a parameter. Because both `x1` and `x2` are still in scope (this happens with captured variables and the way the compiler handles lambda expressions), we pass them to `Console.WriteLine` in order to print the addition of those two ints.

Maybe looking at this way will make it clearer:

```
StringLengthCont("One", new Action<int>(x1 => 
                        StringLengthCont("Two", 
                                         new Action<int>((x2) => 
                                         Console.WriteLine(x1 + x2)))));
```

Or perhaps this way:

```
void AddLengthsCont()
{
    StringLengthCont("One", x1 => CallStringLengthAgain(x1));
}

private void CallStringLengthAgain(int x1)
{
    StringLengthCont("Two", x2 => Console.WriteLine(x1 + x2));
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely fascinating, I had no idea that it was performing all that magic "under the hood".

Comment: your second example is misleading. It is not the same as what actually happens behind the scenes.

Comment: @Selman22 I did not attempt to describe what happens "behind the scenes". What i ment to do is try to explain the problem in a simpler way of viewing. No where in my answer did i say that the OPs code gets translates into a named method.

Answer (score 2):

No, it takes one integer. But `x1` is also visible, in cases where you are not quite sure what kind of code is generated it may be helpful to look at generated IL Code.

In this case to understand how second labmda accesses `x1`, you need to understand closures.

The second method, close over the variable `x1` in a class, here is the generated `IL` code:

[image]

You see there is a class that has x1 field, and this is the code for `<AddLengthsCont>b__2` method which is your inner lambda:

```
    .method assembly hidebysig instance void 
        '<AddLengthsCont>b__2'(int32 x2) cil managed
{
  // Code size       17 (0x11)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      int32 ConsoleApplication9.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0'::x1
  IL_0006:  ldarg.1
  IL_0007:  add
  IL_0008:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_000d:  nop
  IL_000e:  br.s       IL_0010
  IL_0010:  ret
} // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass0'::'<AddLengthsCont>b__2'
```

What it does is to get value of `x1` field add it to the passed argument (`x2`) then call `Console.WriteLine(int32)`

This is the code for your first lambda:

```
    .method private hidebysig instance void  '<AddLengthsCont>b__1'(int32 x1) cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       40 (0x28)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class ConsoleApplication9.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0' 'CS$<>8__locals0')
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication9.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0'::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldarg.1
  IL_0008:  stfld      int32 ConsoleApplication9.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0'::x1
  IL_000d:  ldarg.0
  IL_000e:  ldstr      "Two"
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldftn      instance void ConsoleApplication9.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0'::'<AddLengthsCont>b__2'(int32)
  IL_001a:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<int32>::.ctor(object,
                                                                                   native int)
  IL_001f:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication9.Program::StringLengthCont(string,
                                                                                   class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<int32>)
  IL_0024:  nop
  IL_0025:  br.s       IL_0027
  IL_0027:  ret
} // end of method Program::'<AddLengthsCont>b__1'
```

This method:

1. Creates an instance of the class that generated by compiler (`IL_0000`)
2. Sets the `x1` field (`IL_0008`)
3. Gets a pointer to the `<AddLengthsCont>b__2` method which is the method that generated for the inner lambda (`IL_0014`)
4. Creates an `Action<int>` by giving it to the pointer to `<AddLengthsCont>b__2`  (`IL_001a`)
5. And passes it to `StringLengthCont` method. (`IL_001f`)

Answer (score 1):

There are special rules when it comes to anonymous functions such as the one in your example:

```
x2 => Console.WriteLine(x1 + x2)
```

> When an outer variable is referenced by an anonymous function, the outer variable is said to have been captured by the anonymous function. Ordinarily, the lifetime of a local variable is limited to execution of the block or statement with which it is associated (§5.1.7). However, the lifetime of a captured outer variable is extended at least until the delegate or expression tree created from the anonymous function becomes eligible for garbage collection.

So the function above has access to all variables in the scope the function is declared in and those variables are saved in a compiler generated class. So the anonymous function gets converted to something like this:

```
class __Locals1
{
    public int x1;
    public void __Method1(int x2) {
        Console.WriteLine(x1 + x2);
    }
}

__Locals1 __locals1 = new __Locals1();
__locals1.x1 = x1;  
__locals1.__Method1(x2);
```